# Where do purchased cars appear?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Grand Theft Auto 5, when you go on the browser and buy a car where does the car appear? I have been looking around the entire map but I haven't found it.

Comment: Have you checked your garage? I don't know that is the answer, just guessing.

Comment: Yes but its not there either.

Comment: Every character has a garage that's separate from the safehouse garage. Cars bought online appear in there.